# what's the best way to apply a mask to an EditText on Android?

Tags: java, android

what's the best way to mask a EditText on Android? 
I Would like my EditText to behave like this decimal number input [here](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/#mm_demos).
Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to programmatically set an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) on your `EditText` by [setFilters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5b%5d%29).

From the documentation:

> InputFilters can be attached to Editables to constrain the changes that can be made to them.

You can even change the users input, for example by adding a decimal point which is what you want if I get you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I built a decimal mask for an edit text that will auto change the edit text to the number of decimal places you want.  Bascially, you listen for text changes and loss of focus.

```
    private void formatNumber() {
    sNumberToFormat = etNumberToFormat.getText().toString();
    sDecimalMask = etDecimalMask.getText().toString();
    boolean periodMask = false;
    String delimiter = getDelimiter();
    String[] decimalMask = getsDecimalMask();


    if (decimalMask.length == 1) {
        return;
    } else {

        if (delimiter.equalsIgnoreCase(",")) {
            //decimal format only currently works with dot delimiters.
            sDecimalMask = sDecimalMask.replace(",", ".");
        }

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(sDecimalMask);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);

        sNumberToFormat = df.format(Float.valueOf(sNumberToFormat.replace(",", ".")));
        //if (maxNumber > Float.valueOf(sNumberToFormat)) {
        if (delimiter.equalsIgnoreCase(",")) {
            sNumberToFormat = sNumberToFormat.replace(".", ",");
        }
        etNumberToFormat.setText(sNumberToFormat);

    }

}
```

The complete demo is [here](https://github.com/techartist/DecimalMasking).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use:

```
android:numeric="decimal"
```

on your EditText

Comment: That would only avoid characters not allowed in decimal numbers. Not actually a mask