# How can we use Input Mask or format input in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, input-mask

How can I format an EditText to follow the "######-##-####" format or input mask in android?
And this EditText only allow number. How can i do that? 
just an example, when the user enter 123456781234 it will change to 123456-78-1234
The Edittext will automatically put "-" using the number given.
If anyone can help and show the code, it will help me alot. Thanks..

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890325/whats-the-best-way-to-apply-a-mask-to-an-edittext-on-android

Comment: guys... If u can show the working code... it will help me.. i need it automatically put the "-" when the user enter the number in edittext... hope u can help...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);
```

Take a look at [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) for more options.

Comment: I hope u can show the working code... sorry, coz i'm new on this.. :(